# How to update from Microsoft.NetCore.App 2.0 to 2.1.4

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I created an ASP.NET Core Web API project in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.2.

When I created it, it was `Microsoft.NetCore.App 2.0`.

Now I want to update to `Microsoft.NetCore.App 2.1.4` but I can't because Visual Studio tells me:

> Implicitly referenced by an SDK. To update the package, update the
>   SDK to which it belongs

I download the latest version of .NET Core and I installed it, but I got the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Latest version of the runtime or the SDK?

Comment: Latest version of the SDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't confuse SDK (=> Build tools) versions with .NET Core versions.

The 2.1.* SDK versioning was unfortunate, the versioning scheme has since been changed and the scheme transition will be (mostly) complete with the release of .NET Core 2.1.

You don't need to update the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` NuGet package as it only contains build references needed to build your application.

For self-contained applications, you can also set the `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` property inside the csproj file, but starting with the .NET Core SDK 2.1.300, you no longer need to as it will know about the latest versions.

Comment: I wondering why I don't update Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0 to 2.1 because I see I have that option but I can't because of the message: "Implicitly referenced by an SDK. To update the package, update the SDK to which it belongs", and in the drop-down, I got "Blocked by project".

Comment: Exactly. don't.
If you want to upgrade to .NET Core 2.1 (will be released in a matter of hours), install the 2.1.300 SDK (follow download pages of https://dot.net) and change the `<TargetFramework>` in the csproj from `netcoreapp2.0` to `netcoreapp2.1`.

Comment: Also, you need to be using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`, not `App`. Once you change the target framework to `netcoreapp2.1` it should automatically install the corresponding NuGet.

Answer (score 4):

As Martin points out above, the SDK and .Net Core Runtime are separate entities.

I went to https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows and downloaded the latest SDK (2.1) and installed it on my local machine. You'll need to close any open VS instances to complete the SDK installation.

Open your project's csproj file and update netcoreapp2.0 to netcoreapp2.1 and while you're at it you can update the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" to version 2.1. This will save you from having to update the nuGet package.

Worked for me. Best of luck.